# strange regex behaviour in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to find every number where more than two individual digits double.  Such as:

- **00000000**12
- 18374**888**09

My code is:

```
if [[ $number =~ (.)\1{3,10} ]];
then
    echo "$number found"
fi
```

It is working but not as expected:
It echo’s out numbers containing on 11, and just them.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean containing on `11`?, also two double numbers means it should match `1122` right?

Comment: 1122 should not appear. i made my question a bit more precise, hopefully.

Comment: What's your input? I think you're looking for ``(\d)\1{2,}``.

Comment: Add `set -x` to your script and see what the `[[` command is actually seeing.

Comment: The upper bound on the brace match isn't necessary. If the lower bound matches it doesn't matter how many more there are.

Comment: sorry, I had a wrong value in my first line, the min should be 3. I'm working in an Ubuntu Server.

Comment: `bash` doesn't support the use of back references in its regular expressions; you would have to write out `1{3,10}|2{3,10}|3{3,10}|...` in full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose GNU grep:

```
grep -oE '(.)(\1){2,9}' <<< "1837488809"
```

Output:

```
888
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with:

```
check="grep -oE '(.)(\1){2,9}'"
if [ $check -gt 1 ]; then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`bash` regular expressions don't support back references, so you are simply looking for a string containing at least one character before a string of 3-10 1s. A correct regular expression would be

```
# Tedious, yes, but not really any longer than a piece of code to generate it
regex="0{3,10}|1{3,10}|2{3,10}|3{3,10}|4{3,10}|5{3,10}|6{3,10}|7{3,10}|8{3,10}|9{3,10}"
if [[ $number =~ $regex ]];
then
    echo "$number found"
fi
```